# Google Analytics event tracker custom social button

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, google-analytics

I have a question about tracking event on google analytics.

I'd like to track my custom social button with google analytics event track but what I did don't seems work well, or maybe I don't know where search on google analytics. 
This is my code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
     $('#fb_btn').on('click', function(e){
        ga('send', 'social', 'facebook', 'send', '<?php the_permalink() ?>');
     });

     $('#tw_btn').on('click', function(){
         ga('send', 'social', 'twitter', 'tweet', '<?php the_permalink() ?>');
     });

     $('#pn_btn').on('click', function(){
        ga('send', 'social', 'pinterest', 'pinned', '<?php the_permalink() ?>');
     });
  });
</script>
```

Obviously I'm writing javascript code on a php page(wordpress) so I print my page with .

My buttons have onclick function. For example facebook button:

```
<a id="fb_btn" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php   the_permalink() ?>" class="social_button_facebook" target="_blank" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=600,height=400'); return false;">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/share/facebook.png" alt="facebook icon"> 
    <span><strong></strong><small class="hidden_ab_test">Share This</small>      </span>
</a>
```

Can can be a problem?

Also I found to add this to my code:

```
'hitCallback': function() {
   console.log('analytics.js done sending data');
 }
```

The console.log write the sentence but if I check on analytics I don't find anything.

Where am I doing wrong?
Thanks!!

Comment: Just FYI, you won't be able to see any results in the standard reports until the data is processed, which takes at least 24 hours. You could try to replace one of the "social" hits with "event" to see if you see the event in Real-Time reports though. This would at least show you if the code is working or not.

Comment: I tried to change to:  ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'facebook');  no data in real-time report. :(